# Google play rejected app while uploaded new Version

Tags: android, google-play

Google play message:

This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.

Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

Vulnerability   APK Version(s)
SSL Error Handler
For more information about the SSL error handler, please see this Android Developers Help Center article.

22

I already updated webviewclient code

Here is my code:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError
                error) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder
                    (MyActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.sslerror_msg);
            builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    handler.proceed();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    handler.cancel();
                }
            });
            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Please share solution if any one face this kind of problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: While uploading newer version, did you changed the version number of your app?

Comment: Yes. I have changed Version number & Version code both.

Comment: Have you tested your code - does it work?

Comment: @Robert Yes, Everything is working fine at my end. I am cross checked two or more times its working fine.

Comment: I think , this error may occur due to third party library.

Comment: I use 
`compile files('libs/InMobi-4.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/rebound-0.3.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/crittercism_v4_5_3_sdkonly.jar')

    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')`

Answer (score 0):

After lots of finding I found a solution. If you got this type error or notification message from google play-store during uploading APK then follow the following steps to solved this issue.

Solution: 
 1.   If you use webView & redirect a website then add this code in your WebViewClient

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError
            error) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder
                (MyActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.sslerror_msg);
        builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                handler.proceed();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                handler.cancel();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
});
```

2. You got this error by using any third party library like InMobi. For InMobi use latest SDK of InMobi. This issue will be resolved in latest SDK of InMobi.

Download InMobi SDK: http://www.inmobi.com/sdk/

For more information of InMobi follow this link: https://support.inmobi.com/monetize/integration/android/android-sdk-integration-guide/